# Saving environment variables in gopass

Tags: 1password

How can I save environment variables (sensitive) in gopass and retrieve them and set in my bash terminal them from command line.

I know this can be done in 1password where the password are stored:

myaccount

- key1 - value1
- key2 - value2
- key3 - value3

Internally this is in json format and can be pull with a command like:

```
   op get item "myaccount" | jq .
 
   source <(op get item ${1} | jp -r --arg key2 "${2} '.details.section[] | 
   select(.title==$title) | .fields[0].v' | base64 -D ")
```

The whole idea is my environment variables must be set in a automate way from a secure vault rather than me exporting them like this:

```
export key1=value1
export key2=value2
export key3=value3
```

Comment: Has anyone used "Summon" with "GoPass" as the provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a late answer, but you could save them into gopass like this:

```sh
echo $key1 | gopass insert store/environment/key1
```

Or if you need them to be base64 ecoded:

```sh
echo $key1 | base64 -w 0 | gopass insert store/environment/key1
```

Then you could source them still using `export`, but sourcing them from gopass, rather than hard coding them.

```sh
key1=$(gopass store/environment/key1)
```

```sh
key1=$(gopass store/environment/key1 | base64 -d)
```

Comment: I have not tested this but lgtm as a solution. Thank @sekthor